# How to add custom Controls in Expression Blend?

Tags: c#, custom-controls, expression-blend

I have a Form created using `Expression Blend`. Earlier when I created one in Visual Studio, I could add a custom control using `Controls.Add()`. An example would be as follows.

```
Using SriClocks;
//////////////////////Blah blah
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    SriClocks.DigitalClockCtrl clk = new DigitalClockCtrl();
    clk.Size = new Size(500, 150);
    clk.Show();
    this.Controls.Add(clk);
    clk.SetDigitalColor = DigitalColor.GreenColor;
}
```

When I create the form using expression blend, I can't use the above method to add a control to the form. by

```
    this.Controls.Add(**)
```

Can someone please let me know how to achieve this task!
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Your first code example looks like a Windows.Forms application, but Expression Blend creates WPF applications. Therefore there is no `this.Controls`-Enumeration. You should add the Control to the `Grid` (or whatever else container you used), like

Class1.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Class1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="About" Height="300" Width="350" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Grid x:Name="grid" />
</Window>
```

Class1.xaml.cs

```
...
public Class1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    SriClocks.DigitalClockCtrl clk = new DigitalClockCtrl { Size = new Size(500,150) };
    this.grid.Children.Add(clk);
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice. I think that's the correct way to handle the problem. When I tried it the way you have mentioned, the compiler gives an error saying that the *** in, this.grid.Children.Add(***) should be a UIElement!!! So, how can I make the clock a UIElement?

Comment: @silverfall - if you have no access to the clocks code, you'll need a WindowsFormsHost : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742875.aspx . If this solves your problem, please accept my answer :)